# Using Junit5, how do I run a method after all tests across multiple classes are run when these tests run in parallely but sequentially within a class

Tags: junit5, extentreports

I will need to dod a clean up, how can I achieve this using junit5 when these tests are run in parallel but sequentially within a class (PER_CLASS)

I was trying to implement Test Engine and customise it. Not sure if there are any other ways of doing it.